# How can I get the uid/euid/gid of the parent process in C language?

Tags: c, process, parent, uid

Is there a way without using /proc or "ps" to know the uid of the parent process (or any other process) ?

I mean like getppid() but I need the UID.

Please don't answer with shell tricks or other language ways.

Comment: It's not clear why you couldn't just combine `getppid` with e.g. the approach suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079449/is-there-a-system-call-for-obtaining-the-uid-gid-of-a-running-process.

Comment: If you specify the operating system narrowly enough, there is probably a way. What is your operating system?