# Unix and Linux /proc PID system

Tags: linux, unix, process, pid

For my intro to operating systems class we were introduced to the `/proc` directory and many of the features that can be used to access data stored in the process ID's that are available in `/proc`.

When I was trying out some commands learned (and a few I looked up) on the UNIX server hosted by my school I noticed that some sub directories that were present in a process, that I created, were a file type called "TeX font metric data" or a `.tfm` file. I figured that was the file type that was used when my professor showed us how to get data from the directories like status and map.

When I entered the command `cat /proc/(PID)/status` to look into the status file I got a random assortment of characters and white space. When  I tried the same command on a process I created in my schools Linux server I was shown the information I expected to see in the status and map files.

My question is:

Why did the Unix server produce the random characters from my process's `/proc/(PID)/status` file while the Linux server gave me the data I would expect from the same command? Also Is there a way to access the Unix `/proc` data by accessing the `/proc` directory?

Comment: This would be better on the  [Unix & Linux stack exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

The Linux procfs you are familiar with, aka `/proc/` is not a POSIX thing.  It's OS-specific and multiple OSes just happen to implement similar things also called `/proc`.

Because no formal standard covers it, it's allowed to be / going to be different on any *nix-like system that implements it.

My guess with /proc/(PID)/status is that your UNIX is dumping the process status in a binary form instead of easy to read plain text.

See also: 
[Knowing the process status using procf/<pid>/status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469276/knowing-the-process-status-using-procf-pid-status)

If you can determine WHAT Unix you're on (odds are, Solaris since there's a free variant) you should be able to find a more specific answer.